# Zipcode Lookups in IE8+ using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an easy way to lookup zipcodes and determine the city and state from just the zip code.  I have it working in Chrome and Firefox but every jquery plugin and javascript library I use doesn't seem to work with Zippopotam.us or Ziptastic.  Does anyone know a better solution for IE8 and up in Javascript or jQuery? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code that is working in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: What plugins/libraries are you using?  What is your current code?  How does it "not work" in IE8?

Comment: You might need to add `XDomainRequest` support to jQuery's ajax calls. Here is the plug-in I use for that: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that should matter for Internet Explorer is which version of jQuery you use. jQuery 1.x branch is intended for IE8 and below. jQuery 2.x branch is for IE9 and up. So you'll need to use the older branch to support legacy versions of Internet Explorer.

Once you have your version selected, the rest is very simple. Firing a request off to a remote endpoint is trivial with jQuery, as you're probably already aware:

```js
$.get("http://zippopotam.us/us/30141").done(function (data) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

You  may run into the problem that IE8 won't load resources from another domain. Since IE8 didn't support CORS you'll have to go with another solution, such as [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This feature of IE is not as capable, but can offer some assistance.

Include [this polyfill](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js) to enable IE and IE9 to make cross-domain requests for data. Since both of these browsers also support [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX), it would be best to use them to target these versions.

Since Internet Explorer 10, [IE supports CORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#cors_xhr) and does *not* support conditional comments.

Comment: Assuming the endpoint supports JSONP and/or CORS.  Also, IE8 needs `XDomainRequest` to do CORS, and I'm not sure if that's in the jQuery core.

Comment: Wouldn't [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) kick in here seeing as it's regular JSON?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: zippopotam.us seems to support CORS.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The jQuery team [has not included](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) support for `XDomainRequest`, but there are polyfills (as I listed above).

Comment: I just tried the sample code you just wrote in IE9 and the polyfill you suggested and its not working. No errors nothing outputted to console.

Comment: @DigitalAce7 Don't load the polyfill from GitHub. There will be a mime-type mismatch. Download the polyfill and load it locally. Here's an example that works in both IE8 and 9: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/F53Us/7/show

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thank you for the example! It works now! Great help!

Comment: For anybody else wondering about mis-matched mimetypes in IE9+, please see [Reducing MIME type security risks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx).